# Remove file data - Python

Tags: python, file, append

```
#name,scores
a,6
b,8
c,2
k,23
d,18
r,13
w,4
h,9
threshold = input("Enter minimum score: ")
```

I have a TXT file of which I want data to be removed below a certain threshold of score.

For example, if he user inputs 10 then the file should output the following:

```
k,23
d,18
r,13
```

Comment: What is this "file"? txt, csv? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @Nelver It is txt, I am a beginner so I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that the name and score was in a text file and you were getting user input from a python file.

#### Code:

```
import sys

threshold = int(input("Enter in a number: "))
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    for i in f:
        num = i.split(",", 1)[1]
        if (int(num) > threshold ):
            sys.stdout.write(i) # didn't use print() because it puts an extra newline
```

---

#### Text file:

```
#name,scores
a,6
b,8
c,2
k,23
d,18
r,13
w,4
h,9
```

---

#### Output:

```
k,23
d,18
r,13
```

Comment: If this helped you, don't forget to approve the answer :)

Comment: name,vote is not in the file. Can you adapt the code

Comment: @Daniel The code still works even if you don't have name, vote in the text file but I removed the code anyways for your convenience :)

Comment: Also, remember to accept this answer so future users can find it easily.